# Pass a C# dynamic object to a method that takes an IDictionary

Tags: c#, quartz.net

Right now, I'm doing this

```
var data = new JobDataMap(new Dictionary<string,string> { {"obj", "stringify"} });
```

But I want to do this:

```
dynamic d = new { obj = "stringify" };
var data = new JobDataMap(d);
```

Is there some secret syntactical sugar that would allow me to do this?

Comment: No it is not possible like that. But why don't you add your dynamic object to the JobDataMap, with a certain key?

Comment: Perhaps you can use [`RouteValueDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc680272.aspx`).

Answer (score 1):

There's no magical way of doing this. There's no way the compiler can know that your Dynamic object really is a Dictionary at compile time.

That being said, you could create an extension method that converts it to a Dictionary so that you could do something like this:

```
dynamic d = new { obj = "stringify" };
var data = new JobDataMap(d.ToDictionary());
```

This blogpost offers an example: http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/05/03/Anonymous-type-to-dictionary-using-DynamicMethod.aspx

Comment: Or perhaps an overloaded constructor that takes that item and creates a dictionary.

Comment: Yes, that's actually easier

Comment: Cool, I figured it might not be possible. Is there a more terse way to define my dictionary, maybe?

Comment: Do extension methods work with dynamic objects or does d have to be an anonymous object?

Comment: You could create an extension method on object. I wouldn't recommend it though. I'd go with the overloaded constructor

Comment: Even if the extension method is on object, it still won't work on dynamic object.